# object push into 2 arrays avoid reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I want to push an object into 2 arrays but my problem is the push only add reference

here is my object:

```
minigroup = {
    "Id": response[0].Id,
    "MemberId": response[0].MemberId,
    "NotMemberId": response[0].NotMemberId
}
```

I'm using this to test:

```
groupCache.push(minigroup);
groupCache[0].MemberId = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
groupCacheOriginal.push(minigroup);

console.log("cache: " + groupCache[0].MemberId);
console.log("original: " + groupCacheOriginal[0].MemberId);
```

log results are:
cache: 0,0,0,0,0
original: 0,0,0,0,0

how to avoid this?

Comment: Just clone the object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
groupCache.push(Object.create(minigroup));
groupCache[0].MemberId = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
groupCacheOriginal.push(minigroup);

console.log("cache: " + groupCache[0].MemberId);
console.log("original: " + groupCacheOriginal[0].MemberId);
```

Comment: use Object.create() before pushing, these will create new ref instead of sending original ref

Comment: is this better than `groupCacheOriginal.push($.extend({}, minigroup));`?

Comment: yes, for your statement you need jQuery plugin also, but for Object.create is pure javascript and support for good performance

Answer (score 0):

```
groupCache.push(minigroup);
groupCache[0].MemberId = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var newMiniGroup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_original));
groupCacheOriginal.push(newMiniGroup);

console.log("cache: " + groupCache[0].MemberId);
console.log("original: " + groupCacheOriginal[0].MemberId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign memory to the object and use it as a method rather than object

```
var minigroup = function(){
    return {
        "Id": response[0].Id,
        "MemberId": response[0].MemberId,
        "NotMemberId": response[0].NotMemberId
    };
}
```

Now try

```
groupCache.push(minigroup());
groupCache[0].MemberId = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
groupCacheOriginal.push(minigroup());

console.log("cache: " + groupCache[0].MemberId);
console.log("original: " + groupCacheOriginal[0].MemberId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware of that, Object.create is not working in IE8 and under. See also in [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)